# ToolStripStatusLabel DoubleClick does not work?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

Does ToolStripStatusLabel `DoubleClick` ever work?

```
Private Sub myToolStripStatusLabel_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _ 
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myToolStripStatusLabel.DoubleClick
  MessageBox.Show("WORKING!")
End Sub
```

Only `Click` works. `DoubleClick` does not even if `Click` is present or not.

Comment: Where are you double-clicking, is it on a panel or the toolstrip status label or even on the toolstrip itself?....try double-clicking on the label itself.... Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I doubleClick on the label itself. Only Click works

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That class has a `DoubleClickEnabled` property which is, by default, `false`.  You'll need to set it to `true` in the properties window.

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

Need to Enable the property `DoubleClickEnabled`=>True.

Similar situation with the `TooltipText` - > `AutoToolTip`=>True